# Guidelines for adding foreign keys to database table - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

While reading [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:292016138754) link, I did not understand the point on avoiding table locks by adding indexes on the foreign key column. Can anyone please help me understand the point?

Additionally, I never knew of the importance of adding indexes to foreign key before reading the same link(thanks to Thomas Kyte and the forum!). Can anyone please point me to more such important implementations that I need to consider when implementing foreign keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume two tables, `PARENT` and `CHILD`.  Assume that there is a foreign key constraint on `CHILD.PARENT_ID` referencing `PARENT.PARENT_ID` and that `CHILD.PARENT_ID` is a required (not null) column, and that no index exists on `CHILD.PARENT_ID.`

When updating `PARENT_ID` or deleting records from `PARENT`, Oracle needs to prevent new transactions from concurrently adding new records in `CHILD` with the values of `PARENT_ID` being removed.  Oracle could use an index against `CHILD.PARENT_ID` to check to see what records, if any, may be affected - and to block new rows using the `PARENT_ID` being affected from being committed until the activity against `PARENT` from committing or rolling back.

However, no such index exists for this concurrency issue.  So Oracle uses the only tool it has - locking the `CHILD` table completely until the operation against `PARENT` commits or rolls back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand it myself, but have you read what [the Concepts Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#BABCAHDJ) says about it?  That explains **what** happens, but I'm not sure it explains **why** it happens.